# C - Error: malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug (lldb)

Tags: c, xcode, error-handling, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write an exercise code. I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

The error is:
Exam_prep-L01E01(27381,0x1000ebe00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff203cffc7: pointer being freed was not allocated
Exam_prep-L01E01(27381,0x1000ebe00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program ended with exit code: 9

int main(){

```
FILE *infile, *outfile;
char op;
float nums[2],res;

if ((infile = fopen("/Users/ozgunkocak/Documents/PoliTo - C/Exam-Study/Exam_prep-L01E01/floats.txt", "r")) == 0) {
    printf("Error in opening the file\n");
    return 1;
}

if ((outfile = fopen("/Users/ozgunkocak/Documents/PoliTo - C/Exam-Study/Exam_prep-L01E01/output.txt", "w")) == 0) {
    printf("Error in opening the file\n");
    return 2;
}

while (!feof(infile)) {
    fscanf(infile, "%s %f %f", &op, &nums[0], &nums[1]);
    
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            res = nums[0] + nums[1];
            fprintf(outfile, "%s %.2f\n", op, res);
            break;
        case '-':
            res = nums[0] - nums[1];
            fprintf(outfile,"%s %.2f\n", op ,res);
            break;
        case '*':
            res = nums[0] * nums[1];
            fprintf(outfile,"%s %.2f\n", op, res);
            break;
        case '/':
            if (nums[1] == 0.00) {
                fprintf(outfile,"Result is undetermined\n");
            }
            else{
                res = nums[0] / nums[1];
                fprintf(outfile,"%s %.2f\n", op, res);
            }
        default:
            fprintf(outfile,"Operator not compatible\n");
            break;
    }
}

fclose(outfile);
fclose(infile);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `char op;...fscanf(infile, "%s %f %f", &op, &nums[0], &nums[1]);`. That is likely to cause a buffer overflow. `%s` is for a string. `char op` can only store one character which means anything longer than an empty string, `""`, will cause a buffer overflow. Use `%c` if it is one char that is to be matched or increase the size of `op`.